# inject uplink audio in call with snapdragon MSM8998

Tags: android, audio, phone-call

I need to inject a recorded message in a live call in a rooted Qualcomm chipset MSM8998 device

I've tried voice mail and it didn't work

Comment: Maybe this will help. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204570/inject-uplink-audio-in-call-with-snapdragon-msm8960-soc)

Comment: this is another chip, but is it also under ALSA? @g3ntl3m3n

Comment: Did you find it anyway?