# Inject uplink audio in call for samsung A52 and A72

Tags: android, audio, phone-call, alsa

I want to develop a feature for an android app so that when there is a call we can play an audio file on a call. This audio file should be played when the mic is muted. In other words, the other side of the call will just hear the audio file nothing else.
I want to run this app on an **Samsung A52 rooted device**. 
Many people said that for this feature I need to create a custom android firmware. In other words I need kernel development. I was sure about it until my client said that hey have a 3rd party lib which is implemented this feature without kernel development.
 I was disappointed until I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204570/inject-uplink-audio-in-call-with-snapdragon-msm8960-soc) related to achieve this feature through running some commands on a rooted android. The post was talking about injecting uplink audio in a call.
The devices I wanted to run the app on them have Qualcomm-based chipsets. Does anyone have an experience related to this topic?

According to the linked post I guess it's possible through running some commands on a shell of a rooted device but I don't know which commands I should use.

Comment: Did you find it anyway?

Comment: Yes, I used tinyalsa library to implement this feature

Comment: can you please send me more details about it?