# Android call with custom voice mp3 file

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm new in Android development (for instance I know that in iOS it's not possible).

I know, that to just make a call I need:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But is it possible to call a phone xxxxxxxxx and then instead of voice the other user should hear a voice file (for instance mp3 file placed in my Android project)?
So the only task of the application is to call a number, to play a file and then to stop a call.

Is it possible with Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android play sound during phone call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703712/android-play-sound-during-phone-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not the answer you are looking for:

There are currently no way to send data to a ongoing call. The google havn't released any API for this functionality. You can only control a call in the sense of ending, muting, parking etc. like [this](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.se/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html). It is also possible to record calls, however, this does not happen by using the any class in the [`telephony`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html) package directly instead by using the [`MediaRecorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android/21331756#21331756)

Found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20858616/1724097) describing the issue closer. It is simply not possible, in most cases not even using NDK. I'll mark this a duplicate, since the answer already exists.

For more curious people, i recommend reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20858616/1724097).